# How can I convert a StringBuilder item in a List of strings in Android Studio using Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin, stringbuilder

I have this StringBuilder item in my retrofit :

```
 retrofitData.enqueue(object:Callback<List<HospitalResponse>?>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<HospitalResponse>?>, response: Response<List<HospitalResponse>?>) {
                val responseData = response.body()!!
                val myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
                for(hospitalResponse in responseData){
                    myStringBuilder.append(hospitalResponse.hospitalName)
                    myStringBuilder.append("\n")
                }
```

and I want to convert the StringBuilder to a list :

```
val hospitals = mutableListOf<String>()
```

How can I  do that ?

Comment: A list of what?

Comment: @ArpitShukla A list of Strings, I mention it in my original post.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of hospital names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options:

1. take the StringBuilder and convert it to a list (not recommended)

```
val list1 = myStringBuilder.toString().trim('\n').split("\n")
```

2. create a list and put the names into the list instead of appending it to the StringBuilder

```
val list2 = ArrayList<String>()
for(hospitalResponse in responseData){
   list2.add(hospitalResponse.hospitalName)
}
```

3. Use the fold function

```
val list3 = responseData.fold(ArrayList<String>()) { list, value ->
    list.add(value.hospitalName)
    list
}
```

Comment: I opted for choice number 2 where I created a mutable list instead of an array list after all thank you for your answer :)